# Прерывание цикла в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, циклы

Всем привет! Такой вопрос. Написал небольшую отгадку на JS. Нужно, что бы пользователь отгадал число от 0 до 1000 и даётся только 10 попыток. Когда попытки исчерпаны, то предлагается начать заново, если пользователь отказывается, то программа прекращает работу. Сама прога в бесконечном цикле написана, т.е. если пользователь нажал НЕТ, то цикл должен прерваться.
Вот код

```js
(function() {

 function num(min, max) {
  return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
 };

 const randomNum = num(0, 1000);

 let counter = 0;

 window.start = function() {

  let userNum = prompt("Введите число от 0 до 1000");

  function isNumber(n) {
   return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
  }

  while (true) {

   function endGame() {
    if (counter == 2) {
     let end = confirm("У вас больше нет попыток! Хотите заново?");
     if (end == true) {
      counter = 0;
     }
    }
   };
   
   if (userNum == null) {
    alert("До свидания!");
    break;
   } 

   while (userNum < 0 || userNum > 1000) {
    alert("Вы ввели число вне диапазона!");
    userNum = prompt("Введите число от 0 до 1000");
   }

   if (isNumber(userNum)) {
    if (userNum < randomNum) {
     alert("Больше");
     counter++;
     endGame();
     userNum = prompt("Введите число от 0 до 1000");
    } else if (userNum > randomNum) {
     alert("Меньше");
     counter++;
     endGame();
     userNum = prompt("Введите число от 0 до 1000");
    } else if (userNum = randomNum) {
     alert ("Вы угадали");
     alert ("Игра окончена!")
     break;
    };
   } else {
     alert("Вы не ввели число! Введите чило!");
     userNum = prompt("Введите число от 0 до 1000");
    }
  }
  
 }

})();
```

Дело в том, что для прерывания написана функция endGame, но break не работает и вот вопрос, как можно реализовать прерывание цикла используя данную функцию или если есть другие варианты, то кто знает подскажите плиз?
Извиняюсь, если что то не понятно!
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верните из функции признак, должен ли цикл завершиться или продолжиться.

```
function endGame() {
    if (counter == 2) {
        let end = confirm("У вас больше нет попыток! Хотите заново?");
        if (end == true) {
            counter = 0;
        }
        return !end;
    }
    return false;
};
---
if(endGame()) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: `if (end == true)` → `if (end)` ?

Comment: Alex Krass, спасибо!

Comment: OPTIMUS PRIME, согласен, можно и так